# Scheduler WinForms Control similar to uTorrent scheduler

Tags: winforms, controls, scheduler

I am building a WinForms application and I need a control that allows a user to select blocks of time on certain weekdays when particular services are enabled/disabled. The desire User Interface is for a component much like the Scheduler in uTorrent shown [here](http://lifehacker.com/286607/intermediate-guide-to-bittorrent).

This control has a grid of colored boxes. The days of the week are along the vertical axis and the hours of the day are along the horizontal axis. The user can click in an individual box to toggle the state of the service on that day during that hour.

Has anyone seen an existing WinForms control with this behavior?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, but for JQuery.  Did you ever figure this out? Or find a common name for that type of control?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I ended up writing one in WinForms which does the job but is very ties to our use-case. I'm surprised there isn't one out there. It feels like it should be a common interaction pattern but apparently not. Good luck